# How to send clicked picture over REST api in C# unity

Tags: c#, rest, unity-game-engine, machine-learning

This is my code to capture the image of webcamTexture.

```
 public void SavePhoto()
{
    Debug.Log(Application.dataPath);
    Texture2D photo = new Texture2D(camTexture.width, camTexture.height);
    photo.SetPixels(camTexture.GetPixels());
    photo.Apply();

    //Encode to a PNG
    byte[] bytes = photo.EncodeToJPG();

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/photo.png", bytes);
    predictImage(bytes);
}
```

This is my code to send image to the api

```
public async void predictImage(byte[] bytes)
{
    ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
    
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://74.235.83.70:80", content);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Debug.Log(responseString);
}
```

This is sending image as byte array but I want to send image as image file. How can I do this? Actually, that api is of machine learning model for image classification.

Comment: Why don't you just build the image from the byte array on the server? That's the usual method of doing it. You don't send an image, you send data. You know it's an image because you know it's an image. The server receiving it would not know or care, the flow that handles it is supposed to know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in tools to encode a texture as a byte array:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToJPG.html